# How can I trigger scripts on a virtual machine when I insert a CD or DVD in the host?

Tags: linux, xen, data-cd, removable-storage

I have a PC running XenServer 6.2.0

It hosts, among others, an Ubuntu VM that I configured to rip and copy my CD/DVD collection to the NAS hosting my media collection.

What I would like it to do on disk insert is:

1. Forward the drive and disk to the correct VM
2. Execute the correct script for audio/video
3. Copy the output to the NAS over SMB
4. Disconnect the drive and disk from the VM
5. Eject the disk.

2 and 3 are pretty straight forward.

1, 4 and 5 are a complete mystery.

How can I achieve 1, 4 and 5?

Comment: Possible? Surely. Worth figuring out? You decide.